# Complex Half plane determined by a straight line $z=a+bt$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-geometry

My question is from chapter 1, section 2.3 of the book "Complex analysis" written by Lars-Ahlfors. The book mentions that a direct line $z=a+bt$ determines a right half plane of $Im(\frac{z-a}{b})<0$ and left half plane of $Im(\frac{z-a}{b})>0$.

I have no idea how the above formula comes. The only thing I know is that for $s$ in right half plane, assume the curve has positive slope, $Im(s)<z=a+bt$ and $Re(s)>z$.

Comment: The line is $\frac {z-a} b \in \mathbb R$ or $\Im (\frac {z-a} t)=0$. So the two sides of the line are $\Im (\frac {z-a} b)>0$. and $\Im (\frac {z-a} b)<0$.

Comment: I understand that $t=\frac{z-a}{b}$ is a real number by construction. Yet I still have no idea how to determine the both sides by $\Im(\frac{z-a}{b})$. Can you please further explain about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The complement of the line has two connected components and you get those components by considering the sign of the imaginary part.

Comment: Sorry I still can't determine the sign of imaginary part for each  side.

Comment: I have the same question, was wondering if you figured it out @Calculus_cupcake ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of a late answer but here goes my explanation.

1. First, note that the equation for a line $z(t)=a+bt$ is equivalent to $\text{Im}\;(z-a)/b = 0$.
2. A line $w(t)$ parallel to $z(t)$ can start at any other point $a'$ but needs to have the same direction as $z$.  So $w(t) =a' + b't$ with the restriction that $b'=\lambda b$ for some non-zero real number.
3. Now, the sleigh of hand part. We know that:

$$\frac{w-a'}{b'}=\frac{(w-a)-(a'-a)}{\lambda b},$$

so that:

$$0=\text{Im}\frac{w-a}{b'}=\text{Im}\frac{w-a}{\lambda b}-\text{Im}\frac{a'-a}{\lambda b},$$
$$\text{Im}\frac{w-a}{b}=\text{Im}\frac{a'-a}{b}.$$

Now, two observations:

4. We set up $w(t)$ to be parallel to $z(t)$.
5. The left part of the last equation in point 3 has the same sign as the right part.

Now, if the two lines don't overlap, $a'$ must lie in one of two half planes. As long as $a'$ doesn't cross over to the other half plane, said equation will either have positive or negative imaginary part.

Example: Try it for yourself on the lines $it, 1+it, 2+it$.